# Polyglossia, French and verbatim

Tags: verbatim, polyglossia, french

Using Polyglossia with `setdefaultlanguage{french}` breaks spacing in `verbatim` and `\verb`: `\verb|a:b|` typesets as `a :b`.  [Minimal working example](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/polyglossia-bug.tex), [GitHub bug report](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/27).

Before I delve into Polygloglossia's internals -- does anyone know how Polyglossia interacts with `verbatim`, and do people have hints about fixing this issue?

Comment: A comment to the <a href="https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/27">GitHub bug report</a> suggests using `\appto\verbatim@font{\nofrench@punctuation}`.  This works quite nicely around the issue.  Should it be done by polyglossia automatically?